# Default routing don't work with pagination on mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pagination

Greetings I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I'm using pagination, it works but when I want to call a query that I wrote I get the error:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think its a problem on routing but I can't figure it out.

Here is my controller:

```
public  ActionResult Index(string searchString, int? omonimipage, int? id, int? courseID, int? idcom, int? elencoimo, int? elecoimobi, int? elencoinsta, int? page)
{
    int elencoomoninumber = (omonimipage ?? 1);

    var viewmodel = new mainview();

    viewmodel.elencoomonimi = db.ElencoOmonimis

       .Include(s => s.ElencoProvinces)
       .Include(s => s.ElencoProvinces.Select(r => r.ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote)) 
       .Include(s => s.ElencoProvinces.Select(r => r.ElencoComunis))
       .Include(s => s.ElencoProvinces.Select(r => r.ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote.Select(q => q.ElencoIntestatis)))
       .OrderBy(i => i.Id).ToPagedList(elencoomoninumber,6);

    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewBag.elencoprovinceID = id.Value;
        viewmodel.elencoprovince = viewmodel.elencoomonimi.Where(
            i => i.Id == id.Value).SingleOrDefault().ElencoProvinces;
    }

    if (idcom != null)
    {
        ViewBag.ElencoImmobiliperID = idcom.Value;
        viewmodel.elencointestati = viewmodel.elencoimobili.Where(
            r => r.Id == idcom.Value).Single().ElencoIntestatis;
    }

    if (elencoimo != null)
    {
        ViewBag.elecomuniID = elencoimo.Value;
        viewmodel.elencocomuni = viewmodel.elencoprovince.Where(
            r => r.Id == elencoimo.Value).Single().ElencoComunis;
    }

    if (elecoimobi != null)
    {
        ViewBag.ElencoimobID = elecoimobi.Value;
        viewmodel.elencoimobili = viewmodel.elencoprovince.Where(
            q => q.Id == elecoimobi.Value).Single().ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote;
    }

    if (elencoinsta != null)
    {
        ViewBag.ElencoInstatiID = elencoinsta.Value;
        viewmodel.elencointestati = viewmodel.elencointestati = db.ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote.Where(
            e => e.Id == elencoinsta.Value).Single(i =>i.Id == elencoinsta.Value).ElencoIntestatis;
    }

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@model automa0._1.Models.mainview

@using PagedList.Mvc; 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

Dashboard


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
<div id="content">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nome
            </th>
            <th>
                Cognome
            </th>
            <th>
                Data Di Nascita
            </th>
            <th>
                Codice Fiscale
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.elencoomonimi)
        {
            string selectedRow = "";
            if (item.Id == ViewBag.elencoomonimiID)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";
            }

            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CognomeCercato)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCercato)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cognome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataDiNascita)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodiceFiscale)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Provinca", "Index", new { id = item.Id }) |

                </td>
            </tr>

    }
</div>
</>
            <div id="contentPager">
                Page @(Model.elencoomonimi.PageCount < Model.elencoomonimi.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.elencoomonimi.PageNumber) of @Model.elencoomonimi.PageCount
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.elencoomonimi, page => Url.Action("Index", new { omonimipage = page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

            </div>
    </table>
    @if (Model.elencoprovince != null)
    {
        <h3>Provinca</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Provincia</th>
                <th>Terreni</th>
                <th>Fabbricati</th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.elencoprovince)
            {
                string selectedRow = "";
                if (item.Id == ViewBag.elencoprovinceID)
                {
                    selectedRow = "success";
                }
                <tr class="@selectedRow">
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { elecoimobi = item.Id })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Provincia
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Terreni
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Fabbricati
                    </td>
                    @if (item.ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote != null)
                    {
                        @item.ElencoImmobiliPerDiritti_E_Quote
                    }

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }

    @if (Model.elencoimobili != null)
    {
        <h3>elencoimmobiliperditti</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Classe</th>
                <th>Consistenza</th>
                <th>Foglio</th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.elencoimobili)
            {
                string selectedRow = "";
                if (item.Id == ViewBag.ElencoImmobiliperID)
                {
                    selectedRow = "success";
                }
                <tr class="@selectedRow">
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { elencoinsta = item.Id })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Classe
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Consistenza
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Foglio
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }
    @if (Model.elencointestati != null)
    {
        <h3>elneco Intestati</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>CodiceFiscale</th>
                <th>Nominativo</th>
                <th>Titolarita</th>


            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.elencointestati)
            {
                string selectedRow = "";
                if (item.Id == ViewBag.ElencoImmobiliperID)
                {
                    selectedRow = "success";
                }
                <tr class="@selectedRow">
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = item.Id })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.CodiceFiscale
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Nominativo
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Titolarita
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }
```

on default its working but wen i navigate to page 2 the url its: http://localhost:49208/ElencoOmonimis?omonimipage=2

Thank you.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger?  Which line is the exception on?  What value is `null`?

Comment: i get a null on viewmodel.elencoprovince.

Comment: Not sure what "ToPageList" is doing, but I bet the problem is in that method. It receive page #2 and perhaps you don't have enough records?

Comment: No i don't think the problem its that i don't have records, but i bet its on the routing but i can't figure it out.

Comment: @EniSpetsi OK so why is `elencoprovince` null?  Your URL doesn't have an `id` value so I can see where it would not be set.

Comment: @EniSpetsi I'd agree that it is probable that `ID` is null so `elencoprovince` is never assigned. If you suspect routing is a problem then do a breakpoint right at the start of the controller method and check the values that you are getting back.

Comment: @D Stanley the default url its : http://localhost:49208/ElencoOmonimis and wen i press select that calls the id the link goes : http://localhost:49208/ElencoOmonimis/Index/1. wen i do pagination the default url changes and from : http://localhost:49208/ElencoOmonimis its getting: http://localhost:49208/ElencoOmonimis?omonimipage=2

Comment: and wen i don't use pagination the method works it shows me the record that its related on elencoprovince.